# 18.04.3 LTS installation media do not detect network controllers on a 10th-generation NUC

Tags: networking, drivers, intel-nuc

The 18.04.3 LTS installation media for Kubuntu (probably other distributions, too) do not detect the network controllers on 10th Generation NUCs. These are the late-2019 models with 10th-generation processors, so I assume they are too new for the installation media to have drivers for them.

`lspci` shows the devices, but they are not showing up in `dmesg` messages, nor of course are the links present (*e.g.*, `ip link list` shows only `lo`). This is a bit of a problem for those of us who like to install updates while installing the machine!

Comment: Your assumption is correct. Late-2017 kernels won't recognize 2019-era hardware. The kernel is not clairvoyant, and lacks the modules (or updated modules) to recognize the hardware that it is trying to interrogate. The installed system will have the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr: When installing on a recently-released machine, if the network controllers are not detected by the installation media, use an old USB-to-Ethernet adaptor instead**.

I was trying to install 18.04.3 LTS on a NUC10i7FNK earlier, but the kernel on the installation media was presumably too old to recognize either the ethernet or the wifi controller.

Instead, I got out a USB-to-Ethernet dongle (all I had was an Apple USB2-to-100BaseT dongle, and it worked, I assume others would as well). The machine was able to connect to the network and pull updates while installing.

I rebooted, ran `apt update; apt upgrade`, rebooted, and both the wired and wireless controllers were recognized! (They may have already been recognized before the update, but I am *not* reinstalling just to check that :) )

Obviously this is not NUC-specific, it could have happened on any sufficiently new machine.

I hope this saves someone some heartache!

Comment: The Ubuntu 18.04.3 media uses the 19.04 software stack, ie. an early 2019 software stack - so I'd have tried the 18.04.4 install media myself (even though not officially released yet still being in *testing*, as it uses the 19.10 software stack).